# Thinking of switching to Linux, a few questions..

Tags: hdmi, raid

Im wanting to switch from windows for a while without having to upgrade to windows 7/8

but i wanted to know if what I want to do is supported..

Im currently using a Gigabyte g41m-es2l and intel E6500 with a radeon hd5450 (connected via hdmi to my tv)

I am in the process of buying a esata raid tower and does it support esata hotswap?

will i still be able to use my HDMI connection with sound?

does it support hard drives over 3tb and raid over 8tb?

Comment: This question is very border line, usually we ask that questions be very pointed, but I will try to answer in the most pointed sense.

Comment: There are at least 3 questions that should be individually asked in order to receive a better support.

Answer (score 3):

In general this is what live CD are for, you boot it up and see if your hardware works.

You can check various online lists for supported hardware if you like, but, such lists are for the most part user maintained and support is going to vary by kernel version.

If you are purchasing hardware, definitely check compatibility lists.

http://www.h-node.org/

Linux supports RAID, but you will have to do some reading.

Other then that, come back if you have a specific question about a specific issue. Broad open ended questions do not do so well on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The Board: [yes](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/12.04/Gigabyte%20Technology%20Co.,%20Ltd./G41M-ES2L/I%3aWerIp%3aDEk%3aI8g%3aNqq%3aBWA/)

HDMA Video: Yes

HDMA Sound: [Sorta](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/04/14/audio-over-hdmi-and-displayport-in-ubuntu-12-04/) I have really good results with my Nvidia card, not that, it will help you any.

eSATA Hotplug: [Yes](http://www.makestuff.eu/wordpress/sata-hotplug-in-ubuntu/) I use in on Ubuntu servers, but should be roughly the same on desktops

Max File System/File size: is highly dependant on configuration. Ext3 for example could support partitions up to 32 TiB. On PCs you probably going to get a max size of 16TiB though. RiserFS is 32TiB. Either way 3 or 8 TB isn't going to be an issue.

Your best best is to try with the liveCD. If it goes smoothly then your in good shape if not, then you have some work cut out for you.